# Tree diagram without nodes and boxes

Tags: diagrams, tikz-trees, forest

I am trying to replicate the following diagram

[image]

Which is quite simple but so far I have with boxes and links as showed in the code

```
\documentclass[tikz,12pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,backgrounds,arrows.meta}
\usepackage{forest}
\pagestyle{empty}

 \begin{document}

 \begin{forest}
  for tree={
 child anchor=west,
 parent anchor=east,
 grow=east,
 draw,
 anchor=west,
  edge path={
  \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}]
    (.child anchor) -| +(-5pt,0) -- +(-5pt,0) |-
    (!u.parent anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
  },
 }
  [Rentas vitalicias
[Capital reservado
      [Todo [Muerte antes del retiro] [Muerte antes y despu\'es del retiro]
  ]
  [Mitad [Muerte antes del retiro] [Muerte antes y despu\'es del retiro]
  ]
]
[Capital cedido
  ]
  ]
]
]
 \end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Which results:

[image]

Any suggestion to make it more similar to the firs picture with longer lines and whithout boxes?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: To remove the boxes delete the `draw` command below `grow=east`. The problem is the tree branches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz,12pt]{standalone}
%\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,backgrounds,arrows.meta}
\usepackage{forest}

 \begin{document}
 \begin{forest}
  for tree={
 child anchor=west,
 grow=east,
 anchor=west,
  edge path={
\noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}]
    (.child anchor)  +(-5pt,-6pt) -- +(-5pt,6pt) --([xshift=-5pt]!s.anchor)
    (!u.parent anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
  },
 }
  [Rentas vitalicias,s sep=1cm
[Capital reservado
      [Todo,text width=3em
         [Muerte antes del retiro] 
         [Muerte antes y despu\'es del retiro]
  ]
  [Mitad,text width=3em
        [Muerte antes del retiro] 
        [Muerte antes y despu\'es del retiro]
  ]
]
[Capital cedido
  ]
  ]
]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**UPDATE**: Changed the <s>minimum</s> text widths of two nodes and the vertical separation, thanks to Alan Munn!

Comment: +1 you might want to add `text width=3em` to the `Mitad` and `Todo` nodes so that the lines they dominate line up. For larger trees you'd need to find the largest node per level and adjust afterwards with some node walk magic.

Comment: @AlanMunn Thanks! Do you know by chance if there is something like a `minimum text width` key or does one have to "invent" it?

Comment: There's a `minimum width` key, but not a `minimum text width` key. But there's another problem with your tree. Because `forest` tries to make trees as compact as possible, it packs the `Capital cedido` node too close to the `Capital reservado` node making the structure unclear. Add `s sep=2cm` to the root node to pull them apart.